# Python Bruteforcing zip file cannot assign to function call

Tags: python, zip, brute-force

I am learning how to access a zip file with python BruteForcing. but I am facing a problem when I do that in the zipF in line 11
that is the exception: cannot assign to function call.

```
import zipfile

zipF = zipfile.ZipFile
zipName = input("File path : ")
passwordFile = open("14MillionPass.txt","r")
for passw in passwordFile.readlines():
    ps = str(int(passw))
    ps = ps.encode()

try:
    with zipF.ZipFile(zipName) as myzip(): #the error is here
        myzip.extractAll(pwd = ps)
    print("Password found \n -> {0} is {1} password".format(ps,zipName))
    break
except:
    print("password not found")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a `break` inside a `try-catch` statement. also, you try to assign a function to the file handler. You can use `exit(0)` instead of `break`

```
try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipName) as myzip:
        myzip.extractAll(pwd = ps)
    print("Password found \n -> {0} is {1} password".format(ps,zipName))
    exit(0) # successful exit
except:
    print("password not found")
```

And you have broken indentation in your program, maybe this is want you want

```
import zipfile

zipName = input("File path : ")
passwordFile = open("14MillionPass.txt","r")
for passw in passwordFile.readlines():
    ps = str(int(passw))
    ps = ps.encode()
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zipName) as myzip:
            myzip.extractAll(pwd = ps)
        print("Password found \n -> {0} is {1} password".format(ps,zipName))
        break
    except:
        print("password not found")
```